# Intercept certain tags to support sites which are born from Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, scope

**IMPORTANT: the difference between this proposal and others previously posted:**
the proposal is addressing only **those *technology tags* which have their exact SE sites already. The complete list:** raspberry-pi, drupal, joomla, blender, magento, emacs, wordpress, tex. Nothing more. No ambitions to categorize tag *unix*. But why questions with the above tags should still end up at [SO] without any warning given? ([SO] should stop drawing the momentum from its own children.)

### Idea

Why we allow to create Stack Overflow technology spinoffs if we then let them stand in shadow of Stack Overflow when it comes to their topics?

Let them give a gift from their parent to start their career.

### Proposal

For the above mentioned limited set of Stack Overflow spinoffs, implement simple **tag-to-site recommendation map**.
Example for actual [SE] sites and [SO] tags:

```
joomla.stackexchange.com <-- joomla, joomla3.3, joomla2.5
emacs.stackexchange.com <-- emacs, emacs24, emacs23, dot-emacs
arduino.stackexchange.com <-- arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-makefile
wordpress.stackexchange.com <-- wordpress, wordpress-3.9, wordpress-4.0, wordpress-plugin
```

### Mechanism

On submitting the question, if a tag for recommended migration is detected,  submit action will get intercepted by dialog asking:

> Based on your tag(s) {tag-name}, the question may be more appropriate to ask at {site-name} site of Stack Exchange network. On dedicated site you might get faster response times and more helpful answers.
>
> [Continue submitting at current site] [Cancel]

If necessary, the first paragraph would be repeated for each target site. For example, tags [joomla](/questions/tagged/joomla),[joomla3.3](/questions/tagged/joomla3.3)[drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) will show two paragraphs ([joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) and [drupal.stackexchange.com](http://drupal.stackexchange.com))

### Scope

Primarily Stack Overflow site.

### Benefits

- many questions will become asked on correct sites solely by effort of their OP's
- a relief for moderators who will get less requests for moving of questions
- topical sites will receive their questions which currently end at [SO]
- moderators and fans of topical sites [won't need to monitor [SO]](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/a/205/324) so much, putting comments `please ask at othersite.stackexhange.com` but they could stay more focused at those topical sites
- topical sites would gain their momentum more quickly, especially those in BETA

### Motivation

Some time ago I decided to help joomla.stackexchange.com with redirecting the traffic from [SO] as few other users from joomla.SE site already do. The reason was that I found that the community of gurus at joomla.SE is more avid than at [SO]'s [joomla](/questions/tagged/joomla) tag where I found many unanswered questions, a good soil for [badge:tumbleweed] in many cases. After OP's got the comments and moved their questions to topical site, they received their replies within one day. But I find such a monitoring *as unnecessary as it is helpful* because it could be partially automated. And this is why I wrote this proposal.

Comment: I'd like to hear from downvoters their view why downsides of this proposal outweight its upsides.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94784/provide-option-to-migrate-when-asking-a-question  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73032/automatically-suggest-asking-on-another-site http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117145/warn-user-before-posting-a-question-with-certain-tags-that-suit-su-sf-more-than http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111740/auto-suggest-wordpress-stackexchange-com-when-wordpress-tag-selected

Comment: @random - Hi! The main difference between questions you linked and my question is that they were too expensive to implement because of their sophisticaed algorithms. But I'm addressing only "hard map" of technology tags (joomla, windows phone, emacs, etc.) which give no doubt about migration and have their SE sites. (And is easy to implement.)

Comment: Don't see the difference between setting a flag in the database and providing a hard map, which the other questions suggest

Comment: @random - honestly, I don't get what in this case 'setting a flag in database' will do. Other questions want to categorize also ambiguous tags like `Unix`. I don't agree witch such complex and expensive approach. I'm suggesting only obvious cases based on **existing SE sites**. Tell me, why those questions suitable for topical sites should still end up at [SO] without any warning given? Are you sure this area cannot be innovated at least by adding something basic?

Comment: I know it's just an example list but you should probably remove Windows Phone from your list, programming questions are off-topic there.

Comment: @PeterJ - removed, thank you